# How to change the class properties in Dojo Like Jquery

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I know that the follwoing line used in jquery to set the property of guide_nav class.
$(".guide_nav").css("display", "none");

Like that is there any way in dojo to set the existing style property of a class.

If there please give me a solution for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm did you RTFM??? :-) http://dojocampus.com/explorer/#Dojo_Query_Styling

`dojo.query(".guide_nav").style('display', 'none');`